# ReactJS. The component's state won't change if click is performed on nested html element

Tags: onclick, reactjs

So, I have the `IssuesList` component, which is the list of issues that I get using ajax and github api, and `DevStatus` component, which sort of wraps the list up and contains all the logic, triggers state changes by two radiobuttons and so on.

**My problem:** When I click on one of the radiobuttons, the `DevStatus` component won't change state if the click was on the text inside the radiobutton. And when I click on the corners of the radiobuttons, the blue areas without text, the state changes perfectly.

Here's the structure of the radiobuttons:

```
  <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

    <label className="btn btn-primary active"
           onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton.bind(this)}
           id={this.CLOSED_ISSUE_ID}>
      <input type="radio" name="options"
             autoComplete="off"
             id={this.CLOSED_ISSUE_INPT_ID}
             onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} /> Closed Issues
    </label>

    <label className="btn btn-primary"
           onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton.bind(this)}
           id={this.OPEN_ISSUE_ID}>
      <input type="radio" name="options"
             autoComplete="off"
             id={this.OPENED_ISSUE_INPT_ID}
             onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} /> Open Issues
    </label>

  </div>
```

Here's the [codepen with the code](http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/ojvOpq?editors=001) and here's the [full page view](http://s.codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/debug/ojvOpq?) so you could better see and understand what I'm talking about.

Please, open the full page view and try to click on parts of the button that contain text and on ones that don't and you'll notice that as long as you click on parts without text - the state changes and if you click on text itself - the state doesn't change at all.

---

Could you please help me with that problem?

---

PS: removing `onChange` from the `input` element is not the solution.

### Update 1

If you go to DevTools and inspect the radiobutton element, you'll see that  inside the `label` tag there're `input` and weird `span` elements. The `span` element is not in the code I wrote, did React automatically add that? For some reason, the `onClick` event listener is not applied to those `input` and `span` elements.

### Update 2

I've tried to add `click` event listener to the radiobutton in the console of dev tools and tried to figure out the target of the clicked element. When I click on the text - it is the `span` element and when I click on place without text - it is the `label` element and that's why the click event is not working.

Can my problem be solved using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, so that it won't create the unnecessary `span`?

Could you tell me please how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is creating a span because your text is not in any div. Also it would create a span if there was any white space (but in your case this is because there is no div around your text).

But the real problem here is the way you check your event. **You need to check e.currentTarget instead of e.target**

Then no need to use the ugly dangerouslysetinnerhtml!

Comment: what do you mean by removing the free spaces around my text? There're no spaces around them, as far as I can see.

Comment: I have edited the codepen according to your update and it still generates the `span`s. http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/ojvOpq?editors=001 Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: But now your problem is solved isn't it ? I mean you don't have to worry about the span.

Comment: As I said the span is automatically created if there is nothing around your text, if you write <div>Closed Issues</div> the span won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

React appeared to sometimes be adding `span` tags around text, no matter if there are the free white-spaces or not. The `span`s didn't allow the `onClick` event to fire when they were clicked on.

So, to force React not to render the `span`s, the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` may be used:

```
  noSpanRender(text) {
    return { __html: `<input type='radio' name='options' autoComplete='off'/>${text}` };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dev-status-page col-centered">
        <div className="graphs">
          <h1 className="text-center page-header">
            Our Recent Closed and Opened Issues from GitHub
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="issues col-centered">
          <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

            <label className="btn btn-primary active"
                   onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton.bind(this)}
                   id={this.CLOSED_ISSUE_ID}
                   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.noSpanRender('Closed Issues')} />

            <label className="btn btn-primary"
                   onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton.bind(this)}
                   id={this.OPEN_ISSUE_ID}
                   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.noSpanRender('Open Issues')} />

          </div>
          <IssuesList issues={this.state.issues} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

It was vital to avoid those `span` elements inside the `input` tag, so using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` finally helped.

Comment: You don't have to use that. This is a bad way to achieve your goal honestly. Do a little test about what I wrote about free space inside a div and react adding span you'll see that you don't need to use this trick at all and that it's much simpler the way i advised you to do.

Comment: I had to use this hack because what use offered didn't seem to work, I didn't have free white spaces inside the tag and the spans were still there.

Comment: I can see white space in the code you posted... On the left of "Closed issue" for example. 
What I wrote is the reason why you have span appearing and the way you treat your problem is not the right way at all.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard I've tried removing the spaces at codepen and it still created the `span`s. I agree that my solution is not the best one, but at least it works. The first thing I did was do what you suggested to do, and after that I tried the `dangerous` solution

Comment: Do this for me, write the label line in one line.
Like this <label><input/>Text Here</label>
It's ugly but please do this test for me and tell me the result

Comment: @FrançoisRichard Did it, the `span`s did get created. You can take a look at the code here: http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/ojvOpq?editors=001 (lines 129 - 136)